# Passport authentication with multiple user models

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I'm using **Laravel 7.3** as backend (admin panel) and API, and I have a multiple **Nuxt** websites authenticating with **Laravel Passport**. So I have the default `User` model for admin panel users and other user models, one for each **Nuxt** website. But **Laravel Passport** *seems* to be only working with the default `User` model.

How should I authenticate the users of the different **Nuxt** websites in such configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 functions that exist on the `Passport` Facade:

```
Passport::useClientModel(Client::class);
Passport::useTokenModel(TokenModel::class);
Passport::useAuthCodeModel(AuthCode::class);
Passport::usePersonalAccessClientModel(PersonalAccessClient::class);
```

You need to implement logic that ties your frontend model relationship to your backend, and instantiate the correct model for the given passport methods inside of a service provider.

Comment: Nice start, pointing to where he could start working on the solution